# Java - Type vs instance type

Tags: java

When I do something like:

```
List<Integer> myList = new LinkedList<>();
```

Is the object "myList" of type List? I am more interested about the correct definition. Would it be correct to say that:

> myLyst is of type List but its instance is of type LinkedList?

That doesn't make sense to me because the object can be only one type. So maybe it would be better to say that it is of type LinkedList but restricted to the interface List?

Comment: myList is a variable which can contain instances of any List implementation. It currently holds an instance of the concrete type LinkedList, which implements the List interface

Comment: The key distinction is that myList is just a reference to an object. Its not an object itself. Think of the variable as a shoebox and the instance as the shoes it contains. The box may be able to hold different styles of shoes, but the shoes themselves are still one specific type of shoe: high heels, trainers, whatever. You can take the shoes out and replace them with another completly different pair of shoes if you want, but it doesn't make sense to say that the box is only for high heels just because that's what's in there at the moment

Comment: The contrasting term you're looking for is *declared type*, which is always a supertype of the instance type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`myList` has a concrete runtime class, and that is `LinkedList`.

But `LinkedList` as a type, is a subtype of `List`, so it is also correct to say that `myList` **is a** `List`.

The thing that is definite at runtime is that an object has only one runtime class, which in this case is `LinkedList`. This class can be read by calling `myList.getClass()`.

But checking type hierarchies, i.e., whether an object is an instance of a given type (class or interface), doesn't require that the type it's being checked against is a class. So:

```
myList instanceof LinkedList //true
myList instanceof List //true
myList instanceof Collection //true
myList instanceof ArrayList //false, 
  //because it's not an instance of ArrayList, 
  //and LinkedList is not a subtype of ArrayList
```

Answer (score 1):

The `LinkedList` class implements the `List` interface. `myList` is an instance of the `LinkedList` class and is therefore of type `LinkedList`.

Since an interface is not a type, `myList` is not of type `List`, as `List`, an interface, is not a type.

I hope this answer should clear some things up?

Comment: I have to respectfully disagree with this answer. `List` is as much a type as `LinkedList`, in the sense that the type system recognizes variables declares as type `List`. `List` is *not* a class, but I would argue that it is a type.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo Following your line of thought, would all interfaces then be considered 'types'? Just wondering.

Comment: Absolutely. I would claim that every primitive type, enum, class, and interface in Java is a type.

Comment: OK. Thank you. I'll keep that in mind in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Java List is an interface that extends Collection interface.[Pic shows the hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GS0UW.jpg)

Now, correct way would be, to say that "myList" is an interface variable currently holding the instance of LinkedList class. 
You can look it from another analogy as well, interface is just an abstract representation therefore we can never create an object of type List thus it can only be used to hold reference of object of the class that implements it.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that the **static type** of the variable is List and its **runtime type** is LinkedList.

This is obviously made possible by the fact that LinkedList implements List.

The distinction is important when discussing overriding (inheritance and virtual calls) and overloading (different methods with different parameters — parameters only take the static type into account)